# undefined reference to modbus_new_tcp Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm very new to C/C++ and trying to connect to modbus. I am using Eclipse with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <modbus/modbus.h>

int main(void) {
    modbus_t *mb = modbus_new_tcp("10.84.4.128", "502");
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get the error: `src/Modbus.c:17: undefined reference to 'modbus_new_tcp'`

In Eclipse I've when to properties and added `/usr/include/modbus` to the `Library search path (-L)` but still get the above error.

How do I define the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use 
`#include <modbus.h>`
directly. Instead, include `modbus_asc.h` or `modbus_rtu.h` or `modbus_tcp.h`. This file `modbus.h` will be included automatically

Answer (score 0):

To compile your code using `cmake`, add the `modbus` to `target_link_libraries`:

```
target_link_libraries([APP] modbus)
```